# Ember Highcharts Component throwing odd error

Tags: ember.js, highcharts

I am trying to implement a dynamic highcharts that changes every time a new model comes in. In `ember-highcharts` documentation, they explain that all needs to be done is implement the `EmberHighChartComponent` and implement a `contentdidchange` observer that observes the model and would change the graph when the model changes

**details here :**

https://github.com/ahmadsoe/ember-highcharts#overriding-chart-redrawing

So when I implement it, it works perfectly and graph changes when there is new content, but as soon as I try to navigate somewhere else on the page, it throws this error:

Even when I emptied the component this happens, which tells me that the problem is in `EmberHighChartComponent`

this is what I have after emptying the component

**dynamic-chart.js**

```
import EmberHighChartsComponent from 'ember-highcharts/components/high-charts';


export default EmberHighChartsComponent.extend( {


});
```

**dynamic-chart.hbs**

```
{{high-charts mode=mode chartOptions=chartOptions content=content}}
```

The Error that I get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'chart.renderTo.removeAttribute')
```

Any ideas whether this is a package issue or I am misunderstanding the implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `dynamic-chart.hbs` file. You extending a component, not wrapping it.